# Setting a date without Setting TIme Javascript

Tags: javascript

I m trying to do the following :

1. Storing Current day +1 (Tomorrow's date) ( CurrentDay  is the StartDay,wrong naming alias,my bad)
2. calculating 7 days from date from 1st Step
3. Everyday checking presentDay, and if is equal to 7th day, run my logic.

Problem I m facing is :

1. The DateObject I store is in a numerical format and it also saves the time. I want only the date for comparison.
2. Is it possible to directly compare dates? I do not really wish to use 3rd party library.

Any help will be appreciated.

Code :

```
var d = new Date();
var stdate = d.setDate(d.getDate() + 1); //output something like 1526407850028 ( last few digits changes every second)

var weeklyDate = new Date();
var wkdate = weeklyDate.setDate(weeklyDate.getDate() + 7); //output Ex :  1526926307437 

var presentDay = new Date();
var pdate = presentDay.setDate(presentDay.getDate());

if (pdate == wkdate) { // I want only date comparison
    // my logic
}
```

Comment: Can't you just set the h/m/s to 0?

Comment: Why don't you take 5 minutes and read https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date ?

Comment: what exactly are you trying to do when you say `pdate == wkdate`? pdate is today and wkdate is today + 7 days i.e. (a) The dates will never be the same (b) the day of week will always be the same... tuesday + 7 days is a tuesday.

Comment: pdate is calculated everyday, so it will be equal to the wkdate which is a future date I m storing.

Answer (score 0):

Try keeping your steps more separate. For instance, why not just compare the date values by calling `Date.prototype.getDay()`? Then you're not working with all of that other stuff. You can also reduce the number of calls to `new Date()`, so the whole thing would be:

```
//calculate target date
let d = new Date(); // returns an integer between 0-6
var stDay = (d.getDay()+1)%7; //tomorrow's day of week kept between 0-6 by modulus

//daily check runs in separate function   
let today = new Date();
if( today.getDay() === stDay){
  //logic
}
```

[developer.mozilla.org - Date.prototype.getDay()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getDay)

Comment: I would like to know what went wrong with the question and it was downvoted?

Comment: You can still work on the date, but if you keep it all together, you have to do a lot more math for the comparisons. In other words, extract the weekday and do that comparison stuff separate, then put it back into the `d` Date variable using `setDay()`. I'm not sure why your question was downvoted, but maybe it was because it wasn't clear what you're trying to do?